# Segmentation fault while inserting into map

Tags: c++

I am inserting 'this' pointer into a map

Does it cause a segmentation fault

My code is

```
client->commandHandlerMap.insert(std::pair<CommandType , CommandHandler*>(CommandType::OrderBookCommandType , this));
```

I am doing this inside the member function of a derived class of CommandHandler

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: which part do u need??Its a big project

Comment: Is the map modified concurrently by different threads?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that `client` is not initialized or has an invalid pointer.

Comment: client has a proper value.I am sure of that

Comment: If you don't provide code, it's only guesswork.